# Make Parent Width Smaller Than Child

Tags: html, css

Is there a CSS property that would allow me to keep the current structure of the top example (nested div) but make the parent width behave as wide as the bottom example (independent divs)

Currently I tried to use "display: inline" on parent but it still stretches to the content width of the child.

```css
.parent {
  display:inline-block;
  background: aqua;
}


.how-it-should-look {
  display:inline-block;
  background: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
Parent Text
  <div>
  Child Text Child Text Child Text Child Text Child Text Child Text 
  </div>
</div>



<br><br><br>
<div class='how-it-should-look'>
Parent Text
</div>
<br>
<div class='how-it-should-look'>
  Child Text Child Text Child Text Child Text Child Text Child Text 
</div>
```

Basically I want the top example to look the same as bottom example with only changing CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to `display:inline` instead of `display:inline-block`

```css
.parent {
  display:inline;
  width:auto;
  background: aqua
}

.parent > div{
  display:block;
  width:max-content;
  background:aqua
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
Parent Text
  <div>
  Child Text Child Text Child Text Child Text Child Text Child Text 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, also nice call on the max-content property

Answer (score 0):

Here is another idea if you want to avoid the use of `max-content` and have better support:

```css
.parent,
.parent > *{
  display:inline;
  background: aqua;
}


.parent > *:before {
  content:"\A";
  white-space:pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
Parent Text
  <div>
  Child Text Child Text Child Text Child Text Child Text Child Text 
  </div>
</div>
```